# How should I calculate push-processing for C41 in B&W chemistry?

Tags: film, developing

I usually develop my cheap C41 200 ISO films (from http://poundland.co.uk) films in B&W chemistry (Promicrol) at 20 degrees for 12 minutes.

If I meter for 400 or even 800 ISO (so I can pretend to be Garry Winogrand) how would you recommend push processing to compensate?

The film is AGFA VistaPlus 200, if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you are after the Winograd look you might wish to consider shooting TriX / HP5+, pushed if you must (both stand being pushed easily). These are old emulsions and will give you better sixties look than C41 films.

Comment: @JindraLacko Can I buy them for £1 a go at Poundland?

Comment: Interesting question. Leads to what you expect to do with the negatives. Quality ingredients are not a guarantee of first class product, but there is only so much you can do with clearly inferior ones.

Comment: @JindraLacko My main aim is to have fun!

Comment: Then you are on right track! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience:
+ 1 stop multiply normal time in seconds X 1.15
+2 stops multiply normal time in seconds X 1.9
Best you test and find multiplying factor for your chemicals.
Best of luck. 
P.S. Likely no need to push process for 1 stop.